# Is it compulsory to use Windows 10 operating system to create Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app

Actually i am using visual studio 2015 and windows 8.1 ,while creating a windows universal app xaml view is not shown means xaml designer view is not loaded so how can i see my xaml design view before emulator.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "universal app". If you're talking about UWP, then you will need Windows 10.

Comment: @BoltClock I want to create application which can compatible with all windows family. Application should work in Windows, Tablate and Mobile phone for both windows 8.1 and windows 10. Is it possible? Currently I am using windows 8.1 and visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an app for windows 8.1 and upload it to the store, then this app will be available also for windows 10 throught the store. If you create an app for windows 10 then this app will not be available for windows 8.1 devices.

In windows 10 you have the abillity to target the specific version that you want with `TargetDeviceFamily`

In windows 10 you can create universal apps that produce a single binary and upload them to the store. (Universal apps)

You can also do that in windows 8.1 and create a universal project that contains 2 solutions that share code with PCL but there will be created more binaries for example 1 for wp and 1 for the store.

Answer (score 0):

You better build and test your app in Windows 10 since this is the new feature introduced in Windows 10.

[Guide to Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an app working on both 8.1 and 10, you should target 8.1 and it will work on 10 too in compatibility mode. If you want both PC (tablet) and mobile, you need to create "Universal Windows 8.1" project which is not real UWP, but simply two different projects for mobile and desktop both referencing shared project with common code, xaml and resources. Btw, [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) are samples for "Universal Windows 8.1" projects.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not compulsory to create Universal app when developing for windows 10

The template is universal by default however you can develop for specific platform by targeting specific device family. Open Package.appxmanifest and look for TargetDeviceFamily

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.11" />
```

You can set the Name from Windows.Universal to specific family eg. Windows.Desktop or Windows.Mobile etc.

You also need to set this on store under App details